# Table Cell HorizontalAlignment is ignored/broken

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm using iText 7.0.0 (the Java flavor) and it seems the table cell HorizontalAlignment is ignored because neither CENTER nor RIGHT works. Can you reproduce this?

[see the pdf screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsZbm.png)

and the code to reproduce:

```
private static void brokenTableCellHorizontalAlignmentPdf(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(output);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
    Table table = new Table(new float[] {15f, 16f, 4f}).setWidthPercent(100);
    for (int y = 1; y <= 3; ++y) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 3; ++x) {
            table.addCell(
                    new Cell()
                            .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                            .add(new Paragraph(String.format("(%d, %d)%s", y, x, x == 1 ? "\n\ntest" : ""))
                                    .setFont(font)
                                    .setFontSize(8)));
        }
    }
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I encourage you to accept Bruno's answer to this question as I find it really thorough and it might be helpful to easier find an answer for other persons who encounter this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look at the [CellAlignment](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/highlevel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/highlevel/chapter05/C05E03_CellAlignment.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

    // Initialize document
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Table table = new Table(new float[]{2, 1, 1});
    table.setWidthPercent(80);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    table.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    table.addCell(new Cell(1, 3).add("Cell with colspan 3"));
    table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add("Cell with rowspan 2")
        .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
    table.addCell("row 1; cell 1");
    table.addCell("row 1; cell 2");
    table.addCell("row 2; cell 1");
    table.addCell("row 2; cell 2");
    Cell cell = new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph("Left").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT))
        .add(new Paragraph("Center"))
        .add(new Paragraph("Right").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new Cell().add("Middle")
        .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new Cell().add("Bottom")
        .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

The resulting PDF when you run this example looks like this:

[image]

There's no problem with the alignment, neither vertical, horizontal, or text alignment.

Answer (score 4):

Oh nevermind! After looking at another answer (which pointed to http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/highlevel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/highlevel/chapter05/C05E03_CellAlignment.java) we should now use `setTextAlignment`. As in:

```
new Paragraph(String.format("(%d, %d)%s", y, x, x == 1 ? "\n\ntest" : ""))
    .setFont(font)
    .setFontSize(8)
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
```